# "the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel that looked" VS "the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel, that looked"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Above all, we boarded the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel that looked as tall as a seven-story building. (From an ACT test)

I know "a Ferris wheel that looked as tall as a seven-story building" is used as an appositive for Wonder Wheel, but why can't it be "we boarded the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel, that looked as tall as a seven-story building" where "a Ferris wheel" is still a appositive and a relative clause modifying "Wonder Wheel"？

Comment: Try dropping your proposed parenthetical and see if it still makes sense. "We boarded the Wonder Wheel that looked as tall as a seven-storey building" would only really work if you're contrasting it to some other Wonder Wheel.

Comment: Idk, I think it works just fine. Could you further explain it to me?